# Issue with Twitter API v2

Tags: twitter, twitter-api-v2

I'm trying to fetch the full text of tweets using the Tweepy library in Python with the Twitter API v2. I'm attempting to query using tweet.full_text, but I'm getting a 403 Forbidden error.

According to the Twitter documentation, this may be due to lack of permission to access full API functionality. But I use free version of API and that one should be enough

***Error***

```
Forbidden                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-50-c4cf22e33ad4> in <cell line: 19>()
     17 tweets = tweepy.Cursor(api.search_tweets, q="React", tweet_mode="extended", lang="en", result_type="popular").items(25)
     18 
---> 19 tweets_list = [tweet.full_text for tweet in tweets]
     20 
     21 

8 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/tweepy/api.py in request(self, method, endpoint, endpoint_parameters, params, headers, json_payload, parser, payload_list, payload_type, post_data, files, require_auth, return_cursors, upload_api, use_cache, **kwargs)
    263                 raise Unauthorized(resp)
    264             if resp.status_code == 403:
--> 265                 raise Forbidden(resp)
    266             if resp.status_code == 404:
    267                 raise NotFound(resp)

Forbidden: 403 Forbidden
453 - You currently have Essential access which includes access to Twitter API v2 endpoints only. If you need access to this endpoint, you’ll need to apply for Elevated access via the Developer Portal. You can learn more here: https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/getting-started/about-twitter-api#v2-access-leve
```

***Code***

```
import tweepy
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModelForSequenceClassification
from scipy.special import softmax


consumer_key = "xxx"
consumer_secret = "xxx"
access_token = "xx"
access_token_secret = "xxx"


auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)


tweets = tweepy.Cursor(api.search_tweets, q="React", tweet_mode="extended", lang="en", result_type="popular").items(25)

tweets_list = [tweet.full_text for tweet in tweets]


roberta = "cardiffnlp/twitter-roberta-base-sentiment"
model = AutoModelForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained(roberta)
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(roberta)
labels = ['Negative', 'Neutral', 'Positive']


for tweet in tweets_list:
   
    tweet_words = []

    for word in tweet.split(' '):
        if word.startswith('@') and len(word) > 1:
            word = '@user'
        elif word.startswith('http'):
            word = "http"
        tweet_words.append(word)

    tweet_proc = " ".join(tweet_words)

   
    encoded_tweet = tokenizer(tweet_proc, return_tensors='pt')
    output = model(**encoded_tweet)

    scores = output[0][0].detach().numpy()
    scores = softmax(scores)

    print(f"Tweet: {tweet}")
    for i in range(len(scores)):
        l = labels[i]
        s = scores[i]
        print(f"{l}: {s:.2f}")
    print("\n")
```

I thought it was a problem with the keys and generated new ones, but unfortunately, it did not help

Comment: They change limits