# Can't recieve full text of tweet in Twitter API V2

Tags: python, twitter, twitter-api-v2

I am trying to receive full text of the tweet, but receive only `...` in the end,

Full tweet text: `This is the full text of the tweet`
I receive: `This is full ...`

This is my code:

```
import asyncio
import logging

from tweepy.asynchronous import AsyncClient

from app.common.config import settings
from app.common.database import get_async_db
from app.db.models.models import InsightModel, TwitterAccountModel
from app.db.repositories.insight_repository import create_insights
from app.services.collectors.base_collector import BaseCollector

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)


class TwitterCollector(BaseCollector):
    def __init__(self, twitter_account_model: TwitterAccountModel):
        super().__init__()
        self.twitter_account_model = twitter_account_model
        self.client = AsyncClient(
            bearer_token=settings.TWITTER_API_BEARER,
            consumer_key=settings.TWITTER_API_KEY,
            consumer_secret=settings.TWITTER_API_SECRET,
            access_token=settings.TWITTER_API_ACCESS_TOKEN,
            access_token_secret=settings.TWITTER_API_ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET,
        )

    async def run(self):
        tweets = await self.client.get_users_tweets(
            id=self.twitter_account_model.account_id,
            max_results=5,
            tweet_fields=["text","created_at"],
            exclude=["retweets", "replies"],
        )
        logger.info(f"Pulled {len(tweets)} tweets, tweets: {tweets}")
        insights = map(
            lambda tweet: InsightModel(
                text=str(tweet.text),
                external_id=str(tweet.id),
                payload={
                    "created_at": str(tweet.created_at),
                },
                insight_tags=self.twitter_account_model.insight_tags,
            ),
            tweets.data,
        )
        async with get_async_db() as session:
            await create_insights(session=session, insights=insights)
```

I tried to research Twitter API but didn't get the answer, this isn't helping me:
[Issue with Twitter API v2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76029151/issue-with-twitter-api-v2)

Comment: Is this for retweets? If so, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70142469/getting-the-latest-tweet-retweet-and-full-text-of-the-retweet-twitter-api-v2

Comment: Is it a retweet? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63540330/get-extended-full-text-tweets-in-twitter-api-v2

Comment: This isn't for retweets